# Can I consume Navision Web Services (Odata / SOAP) using Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navision

I am trying to consume Web Services (NAV 2016) using Ruby on Rails but stuck at a point
when hitting the (SOAP) URL system returns an HTTP authentication error.

Does any one have idea or any links for same.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks,
kapil

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this happens when NTLM authentication in the NAV service configuration file is disabled (and it is disabled by default).

CustomSettings.config should have the following line:

```
<add key="WebServicesUseNTLMAuthentication" value="true"></add>
```

Default setup for "WebServicesUseNTLMAuthentication" is "false".

Comment: Thank you. I already made this change in navision side(in CustomSettings.config). yet I am able to authentication with navision from ruby on rails and got all methods of webservices but not able to get data from those methods. Do you have any suggestion on same?
Have you consumed body of webservice from navision using post method or readbyrecid method?

Thanks,
kapil

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to get authenticate with navision webservices using following gems

gem 'httpi', :git => 'git://github.com/bensie/httpi.git', :branch => 'ntlm'

gem "pyu-ntlm-http", :git => "git://github.com/lxcid/ntlm-http.git", :branch =>"1.9_utf16_bom_fix"

gem 'savon', '~> 0.8'

I have use proper server ,port,server_instance,company name

Thanks,
kapil